# Configure a first cell by default in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

TIs there a way to configure a default first cell for a specific python kernel in the Jupyter notebook? I agree that default python imports go against good coding practices.

So, can I configure the notebook such that the first cell of a new python notebook is always

```
import numpy as np
```

for instance?

Comment: sorry, autocorrect changed jupyter in the title for Jupiter :S

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? It would be very useful since the first thing I do in a new notebook is a bunch of standard imports!

Comment: It looks like the jupyter devs don't want to do that, but suggest writing a notebook extension. Hopefully someone who knows how to do that will do so!
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/640

Answer (score 18):

Creating an IPython profile as mentioned above is a good first solution, but IMO it isn't totally satisfying, especially when it comes to code sharing.

The names of your libraries imported through the command exec_lines do not appear in the notebook, so you can easily forget it. And running the code on another profile / machine would raise an error.

Therefore I would recommend to use a Jupyter notebook extension, because the imported libraries are displayed. **It avoids importing always the same libraries at the beginning of a notebook.**
First you need to install the nbextension of Jupyter.
You can either clone the repo : https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
or use the pip : `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Then you can create a nb extension by adding a folder 'default_cells' to the path where the nb extensions are installed. For example on Ubuntu it's /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/., maybe on windows : C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\nbextensions\

You have to create 3 files in this folder:

- main.js which contains the js code of the extension
- default_cells.yaml description for the API in Jupyter
- README.MD the usual description for the reader appearing in the API.

I used the code from : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1451my main.js is :

```js
    define([
        'base/js/namespace'
    ], function(
        Jupyter
    ) {
        function load_ipython_extension() {
          if (Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().length===1){
       //do your thing
            Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_above('code', 0).set_text("# Scientific libraries\nimport numpy as np\nimport scipy\n\n# import Pandas\n\nimport pandas as pd\n\n# Graphic libraries\n\nimport matplotlib as plt\n%matplotlib inline\nimport seaborn as sns\nfrom plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, download_plotlyjs\ninit_notebook_mode()\nimport plotly.graph_objs as go\n\n# Extra options \n\npd.options.display.max_rows = 10\npd.set_option('max_columns', 50)\nsns.set(style='ticks', context='talk')\n\n# Creating alias for magic commands\n%alias_magic t time");
          }
        }
        return {
            load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension
        };
    });
```

the .yaml has to be formatted like this :

```yaml
    Type: IPython Notebook Extension
    Compatibility: 3.x, 4.x
    Name: Default cells
    Main: main.js
    Link: README.md
    Description: |
      Add a default cell for each new notebook. Useful when you import always the same libraries$
    
    
    Parameters:
    - none
```

and the README.md

```markdown
    default_cells
    =========
    
    Add default cells to each new notebook. You have to modify this line in the main.js file to change your default cell. For example
    
    `Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_above('code', 0).set_text("import numpy as np/nimportpandas as pd")`
    
    
    You can also add another default cell by creating a new line just below :
    
    `Jupyter.notebook.insert_cell_above('code', 1).set_text("from sklearn.meatrics import mean_squared_error")`
    
    **Don't forget to increment 1 if you want more than one extra cell. **
```

Then you just have to enable the 'Default cells' extension in the new tab 'nbextensions' which appeared in Jupyter.

The only issue is that it detects if the notebook is new, by looking at the number of cells in the notebook. But if you wrote all your code in one cell, it will detect it as a new notebook and still add the default cells.

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Can't believe this extension still doesn't come packaged out of the box.

Answer (score 9):

Another half-solution: keep the default code in a file, and manually type and execute a `%load` command in your first cell.

I keep my standard imports in firstcell.py:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...
```

Then in each new notebook, I type and run `%load firstcell.py` in the first cell, and jupyter changes the first cell contents to

```
# %load firstcell.py
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

If you really just want a single import statement, this doesn't get you anything, but if you have several you always want to use, this might help.

Comment: I think this answer is nice and handy. You could combine it with the one I suggested too, so that it loads the path to the file where the imports are written `%load firstcell.py`

Comment: This is quite nice, since the code is literally loaded into the cell after running the `%load` magic

Answer (score 2):

Go there:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/
```

You can read the README:

> This is the IPython startup directory
>
> .py and .ipy files in this directory will be run *prior* to any code
>   or files specified via the exec_lines or exec_files configurables
>   whenever you load this profile.
>
> Files will be run in lexicographical order, so you can control the
>   execution order of files with a prefix, e.g.::
>
> ```
> 00-first.py
> 50-middle.py
> 99-last.ipy
> ```

So you just need to create a file there like `00_imports.py` which contains:

```
import numpy as np
```

if you want to add stuff like `%matplotlib inline` use `.ipy`, which you can use directly as well.

Alternatively, there seems to exist another solution with `notebook extension`, but I don't know how it works, see here for the github issue of the topic:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/640

HTH

Comment: I guess this will bind the notebook to your system. Executing the notebook on a different machine will result in errors. This is probably not a good solution as notebooks cannot be shared anymore.

Comment: @jeanrjc Thanks for the idea! However, @ cel got exactly my point. This will generate code that's hard to port unless one documents all the implicit imports in 00-first.py.

That's why what I want is that for every new python notebook I start, the first cell is already filled in with some specific code.

Comment: @jrjc A notebook should be self-sufficient and self-contained, especially if they end up on github or are shared differently. You suggest to put essential code in seperate files, hidden in someone homedir. That results in errors. The error "No module scipy" is OK, as it clearly suggests to install scipy, but the error "imread not found" because `from scipy.misc import imread` was not shared, is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which I find to be quite handy is to use %load command in your notebook.

As an example I stored the following one line code into a python file __JN_init.py

```
import numpy as np
```

Then whenever you need it, you could just type in:

```
%load __JN_init.py
```

and run the cell. You will get the intended package to be loaded in. The advantage is that you could keep a set of commonly used initialization code with almost no time to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

1 - Create a startup script that will check for a .jupyternotebookrc file:

```
# ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/run_jupyternotebookrc.py

import os
import sys

if 'ipykernel' in sys.modules: # hackish way to check whether it's running a notebook
    path = os.getcwd()
    while path != "/" and ".jupyternotebookrc" not in os.listdir(path):
        path = os.path.abspath(path + "/../")
    full_path = os.path.join(path, ".jupyternotebookrc")
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        get_ipython().run_cell(open(full_path).read(), store_history=False)
```

2 - Create a configuration file in your project with the code you'd like to run:

```
# .jupyternotebookrc in any folder or parent folder of the notebook

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
```

You could commit and share your .jupyternotebookrc with others, but they'll also need the startup script that checks for it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and also flexible solution is to create template notebooks e.g.
One notebook with specific imports for a python 2.7 kernel:

> a_template_for_python27.ipynb

Another notebook with different imports:

> a_template_for_python36.ipynb

The preceding `a_` has the advantage that your notebook shows up on top.

Now you can duplicate the notebook whenever you need it. The advantage over `%load firstcell.py` is that you don't need another file.

However the problem of this approach is that the imports do not change dynamically when you want to start an existing notebook with another kernel.

Answer (score 1):

While looking into the same question I found the Jupytemplate project from I was looking into the same question and found a pretty good lightwightb solution for this kind of problem. Jupytemplate copies a template Notebook on top of the notebook you are working on when you initialise the template or press a button. Afterwords the inserted cells are a completly normal part of your Notebook and can be edited/converted/downloaded/exported/imported like you do with any other notebook.

[image]

[Github Project jupytemplate](https://github.com/xtreamsrl/jupytemplate)