# How can I run arbitrary code in the context of a Jupyter kernel at startup time?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I start a new Jupyter Python kernel, is there any way to run a startup python script that can import arbitrary items into python process that is running in the notebook? Currently I have to copy and paste custom code into the first cell - but since I always want to run that code it would be nice to do it automatically on startup.

Answer (score 0):

- if you have pycharm then you can create a template prefilled with your most used libraries (but this seems only work for .py files)
- a better solution is to [configure default cells for Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194865/configure-a-first-cell-by-default-in-jupyter-notebooks/43156449)
- not totally relavant but the [notebook extensions](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator) has a feature for initialization cells which help you mark which cells are run auto each time a notebook is loaded.

See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/musketeer191/5086795075d1eec6c05e7ace4d970282) for other useful tips on Jupyter.